# By what kind of means

Tags: prepositional-phrases, interrogatives

I had a sentence

***It was not very convenient to cut bread by knife***

Then I made it interrogative with a special question:

***By what was it not very convenient to cut bread?***

Then decided to change "by" for "by means of" and got

***It was not very convenient to cut bread by means of knife***

Then interrogative:

***By means of what was it not very convenient to cut bread?***

And then I invented a phrase that didn't have to exist because it was extremely congested:

***By what kind of means was it not very convenient to cut bread?***

Is ***"by what kind of means"*** correct and what is its difference from ***"by means of what"***?

Comment: It's correct but awkward.  And "by what kind of (anything)" is logically different from "by what (anything)" because the first is more generalized, more abstract, or both.

Comment: or both?

So, "by what kind of means" is more precise than "by means of what"?

Comment: We cut bread _with a_ knife, not _by_ knife.

Comment: So, "by knife" would consider me conidering the knife an alive creature?

Comment: No, it's just that we don't say it that way. You travel by car or train, but you cut with a knife and write with a pencil.

Comment: What is the difference between "car" and "knife"?